# Issue in Adding data into database using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I am getting the following exception while adding data into database:

org.hibernate.HibernateException: The database returned no natively generated identity value

I am using the following code:

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();

session.save(user);
logger.info("Successfully data insert in database");
tx.commit();
isSaved = true;
```

Please let me know what is wrong. Thankx

Comment: We are going to need more information. Are you using Annotations or XML mapping files? Can we see the relevant mappings? Can we see the relevant DB schema?

Comment: i am using hbm
<hibernate-mapping>
 <class name="com.test.User" table="user">
 
  <id name="userName" column="user_name">
   <generator class="identity" />
  </id>  
  
  <property name="userCode">
   <column name="user_code" />
  </property>
  
    
   </class>
 
</hibernate-mapping>

Comment: User bean has userName and userCode and database has user_name and
user_code as columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if the database doesn't support the identity id generator. Based on your mapping you are probably using the userName as the ID column, which would mean that you probably want to set the generator class to *assigned* since the username (= id) will be picked manually (and not auto generated by the database):

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.test.User" table="user">
        <id name="userName" column="user_name">
            <generator class="assigned" />
        </id>
        <property name="userCode">
        <column name="user_code" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```